# SSH : all full-screen commands (vi, top, screen...) fail

Tags: ssh, networking

this is a weird one. I'm connecting to a bunch of machines (all running Debian 11) through an openVPN.

I can connect to all three machine fine. However, as soon as I run a full-screen command such as `less`, `top`, `vim`, `screen`, etc the terminal blanks and freezes.

Some other random commands freeze, for instance `lsmod` displays about 10 lines then freezes.

transferring a file through `scp` freezes the connection too. When using a shared SSH connection, the whole connection is killed by using `scp`.

I have exactly the same behaviour on all three systems. I suspect some networking problem such as MTU mismatch or something similar. Any idea on how to debug this?

Miscellaneous information :

- yesterday the machines (then running Debian 10) were "dist-upgraded". At some point after the upgrade, they all encountered unexplained local network problems (lots of lost pings, etc). The machines all use dual aggregated 10GigE links, so after a while we deleted the LACP (802.3ad) bonds and created balance-alb bonds instead, which work fine *on the local network*.
- all three machines use different network cards using different drivers (two use Intel Ethernet 82599ES, one Myricom Myri-10G).
- all three machines are configured for standard, 1500 mtu.

Edit : here is the "scp -vvv" output:

```
Authenticated to XXXXX ([XXXXX]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env MOTD_SHOWN
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug1: Sending env LANG = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_CLASS
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f conf_samba.txt
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 46
Sending file modes: C0644 2291 conf_samba.txt
debug2: channel 0: written 46 to efd 6
Sink: C0644 2291 conf_samba.txt
conf_samba.txt                                                                                                                                                0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
```

Comment: Do these command (on Linux) receive the expected replies? First `ping othersystem` (to check ping is allowed), then `ping -M do -s 1472 othersystem`? If they do, nothing discovered, if only the 1st,  then there's something dropping ICMP needed for PMTUD (if both don't, then nothing discovered either). OpenVPN (or any VPN) means PMTUD is probably needed.

Comment: Honestly I suspect they will work and the problem is more difficult than this... (since it's related to a change of behavior after an upgrade).

Comment: mtu problem....

Comment: When connected to the servers, they can ping each other no problem. From the VPN client I can `ping -M do -s 1472 server` no problem... but `scp` hangs, ditto `less` from ssh... Weird uh?